# cyclic tab order with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a nice way to set a desktop-like tab order in a form with jquery? the form has four text inputs and two buttons; after the last button loses focus, I want the first text input to get focus and start tab order from the beginning (to 2nd tb, to 3rd tb...). I did this:

```
    $('body').delegate('#second_button', 'blur', function() {
        $('#first_input_text').focus();
    });
```

but it only works in Opera. Chrome IE9, And Firefox do set focus on first text input but when user press tab again it goes to address bar instead of the second text input. I could set above binding to all elements in cycle but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you mean [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tabindex attribute to each form element - example :

```
<FORM action="..." method="post">
<P>
<INPUT tabindex="1" type="text" name="field1">
<INPUT tabindex="2" type="text" name="field2">
<INPUT tabindex="3" type="submit" name="submit">
</P>
</FORM>
```

[Documentation here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1)

Comment: Already tried that but when last element in tab order loses focus then next elements - out of interest group gets focus, then ui and just after it is returned to element with tab index 1